# How does Gearman communicate with workers?

Tags: php, gearman

I'm looking to setup Gearman in a distributed server environment. What protocol/method does it use to send jobs to `[ip-address-1]` and `[ip-address-2]` below?

```
$worker= new GearmanWorker(); 
$worker->addServers("[ip-address-1],[ip-address-2]");
```

Comment: [Gearman protocol](http://gearman.org/protocol/) - I guess that means proprietary

Comment: [Copyright](https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/blob/master/COPYING)

Answer (score 1):

I don't now how PHP do that, but with regard to gearman [protocol](http://gearman.org/protocol/) the worker have to register itself with `CAN_DO` or `CAN_DO_TIMEOUT` command by gearman server. For instance Perl binding provides [register_function](https://metacpan.org/pod/Gearman::Worker#$worker-%3Eregister_function($funcname,-$subref)) method. After registration the worker have periodically to send `GRAB_JOB` request to the servers.

The clients send jobs to the server with one of the `SUBMIT_JOB` commands.